# I have a cycle error in c ++

Tags: c++, cycle

The error is generated when the user adds the times he wants to repeat the cycle, but he keeps repeating the cycle without end

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char resp, copcion, varied, tprod;
    int cfab, ncod, num;

    cout << "How many products do you want to register ?, enter the respective number";
    cin >> num;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter the product type If you are a Child (n) or Adult (a)";
        cin >> tprod;

        if ((tprod != 'n') && (tprod != 'N') && (tprod != 'a') && (tprod != 'A'))
        {
            cout << "ERROR: The product type is only Children (n) or Adults (a)" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Enter your Variety for Salted (s) and Sweets (d)";
        cin >> varied;

        if ((varied != 'd') && (varied != 'D') && (varied != 's') && (varied != 'S'))
        {
            cout << "ERROR: The variety of products are only Sweets (d) or Salted (s)" << endl;
        }
        //Code range
        //Salted 1 to 10
        //Sweets 11 to 20

        cout << "Enter the product code you wish to assign";
        cin >> ncod;

        if (ncod > 20)
        {
            cout << "ERROR: There is a range of numbers, you exceeded that amount" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Enter the respective amount";
        cin >> cfab;

        if (cfab = 0)
        {
            cout << "ERROR: Amount entered is not valid";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In advance thanks for solving the doubts.

Comment: `cfab=0` -> `cfab == 0` ?

Comment: The best tool to use for this is your debugger.

Comment: @Charles Eclipse already marks it as a potential problem, when I copy/pasted the code into it for autoformatting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code reads in a number to the `num` variable and does a `while(num>0)` - but it never changes `num` so it is always greater than 0 and loops forever.

Maybe change `while(num>0) {` to `while(num-- > 0) {` to decrement `num` each time and the loop will run `num` times instead of inifinite times.